# Asymptotic Estimation of a function ${\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2} dt}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, approximation-theory

[image]I'm reading a book "Theory of Approximation of Functions of a Real Variable" by A.F Timan

On the page 14 there is an asymptotic estimation:"... It is an integral function of the first degree, bounded on the real axis  and monotonically increasing. Hence
$1 - |g(x)| = O(\frac{1}{1+|x|})$, where $g(x) = {\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}}{t^2} dt}$ "

I don't know exactly how to get this estimation.

I think about $\int \frac{\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}}{x^2} dx=-\frac 12\int \frac { \cos(t)-1}{t^2} dt$, then integrate by parts but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Mark Viola: $-\infty<x<+\infty$

Comment: That does not help.  Are you seeking a "small" argument approximation?  Or are you seeking a large argument approximation?

Comment: @Mark Viola: I added a page of this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x\geq 1$ we have
$$
1-g(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_x^{+\infty}\frac{\left(\sin(t/2)\right)^2}{t^2}dt\leq
\frac{4}{\pi}\int_x^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^2}=O(1/x)=O(1/(1+|x|)).
$$
For $|x|\leq 1$ both $1/(1+|x|)$ and $1-g(x)$ are bounded continuous functions so the statement is true, then for $x\leq -1$ use that $g(-x)=-g(x)$.

Comment: thank you for your respond. It looks strange to me why the author of the book used the second estimation $O(1/(1+|x|)$.  The first one $O(1/x)$ is more usual for me.

Comment: But $O(1/(1+|x|))$ is a convenient notation to summarize the properties of $1-g(x)$ along the whole real line. $O(1/x)$ would also be correct, but not as sharp as the other one (indeed $1-g(x)\sim 1$ is bounded near $x=0$, whilst a function which is $O(1/x)$ could even blow up at $x=0$).